# Determine if point is inside boost::geometry::linear_ring accounting orientation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I want to determine if point is inside polygon with [boost::geometry](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html).

I use function [boost::geometry::within](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html) and type `boost::geometry::linear_ring<boost::geometry::point_2d>` to specify contour.

All work fine if I don't need to account orientation of contour.
But in my case I want to account orientation. I mean that if inner region for specific contour is considered limited by its border and finite, then the inner area of inverted contour should be infinite - complementation to area of initial contour.

Is it possible to account orientation of contour in `within` function?

It can be expessed in the following code:

```
// Create contour which defines square
boost::geometry::linear_ring<boost::geometry::point_2d> contour;
contour.push_back(boost::geometry::point_2d(4, 2));
contour.push_back(boost::geometry::point_2d(2, 2));
contour.push_back(boost::geometry::point_2d(2, 4));
contour.push_back(boost::geometry::point_2d(4, 4));
contour.push_back(boost::geometry::point_2d(4, 2));

// Create contour which defines square with opposite direction.
boost::geometry::linear_ring<boost::geometry::point_2d> contourInverted = contour;
std::reverse(contourInverted.begin(), contourInverted.end());

// Specify point inside square
boost::geometry::point_2d testPoint(3, 3);

// Perform tests
bool ret1 = boost::geometry::within(testPoint, contour);
bool ret2 = boost::geometry::within(testPoint, contourInverted);
```

After execution of the code above `ret1` and `ret2` are both `true`. But I would have `ret1 != ret2`.

In general I need to obtain functionaly when `ret1 != ret2` for any `testPoint` (I don't consider border cases here when point is exactly on the border or polygon is degenerated etc...)

I tried [different strategies](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_3_with_strategy.html#geometry.reference.algorithms.within.within_3_with_strategy.available_strategies) to pass to `boost::geometry::within`, but I have not obtained what I need.

It seems that functionality which I need or similar is implemented somewhere in the `boost::geometry`, because the [documetation for within](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html) has example of polygon with holes. But I have not realised how to use it for my case.

There is also quite simple workaround. I need just write a code to determine orientation of contour. Then I just negate or not result of `within` function depending on contour orientation. But if `boost::geometry` has implementation already I don't want to duplicate it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, neither Boost.Geometry nor Boost.Polygon work with "infinite" areas you defined. They do work with polygon with holes and even sets of such polygons.

You might consider adding a big rectangle limiting your universe. Then you can define inverted contour as a hole in such rectangle.

BTW, in many cases one can avoid converting box to a contour. Boost.Geometry provides an adapter "box_view" which allows to use box as if it were a (positively oriented) contour.

As for orientation of an arbitrary contour, probably the easiest way is to compute its area. On the other side, for well-formed ring the orientation is known at compile-time and is provided by meta-functions  `traits::point_order`, see details [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_ring.html)

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks:

- In Boost.Geometry there is no `bg::linear_ring<>`, there is `bg::model::ring<>`.
- `bg::model::ring<>` is a model of what in Boost.Geometry is called a Ring which is an areal geometry, a simple Polygon without holes.
- Ring differs from OGC LinearRing, it's an areal (2d) geometry and it has an orientation. OGC LinearRing is 1d with no orientation.
- It's possible to set an orientation of `bg::model::ring<>` in compile-time by passing the 2nd template parameter, see [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_ring.html).
- a value returned by the `area()` function for a reversed areal (cartesian) geometry is a negative area (not infinite). But not all functions works for reversed geometries because the library considers them as invalid in general.

In Boost.Geometry the data must reflect the compile-time setup of a geometry, in this case the orientation set for the Ring at compile-time. Otherwise the results may be unexpected. In your case the same value is returned. You can call `bg::correct()` to automatically correct the orientation and closure before passing the geometry to other functions. You can also call `bg::is_valid()` to check if everything is ok with your geometry.

So if you want to check if a point overlaps an interior of a geometry you can call `within(pt, ring)`. And if you want to check if a point is on the boundary or overlapping the exterior then `!within(pt, ring)` should return what you need, which is of course obvious.

If you wanted to take the boundary into account so check if a point overlaps the interior or boundary then you could use `covered_by(pt, ring)`, `!disjoint(pt, ring)` or `intersects(pt, ring)`. Obviously, the complement in this case could be `!covered_by(pt, ring)`, `disjoint(pt, ring)` or `!intersects(pt, ring)`.

In the case of Pt/Ring, internally the same code is used to check all of those spatial relations so it shouldn't matter which one is called.